# Proof of an assertion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Show $k^k = n^c$ is such that $k = \frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n}$. Note: $\log = \log_2$. To see this, take the log of both sides

$k^k = n^c$ becomes $k{\log}k = c{\log}n$. Now, take $k = c * (\frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n})$, for $c = 1,000,000$ and $c = .000001$

$k*{\log}k = 1,000,000 * (\frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n}){\log}1,000,000 * (\frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n})$ too big

$k*{\log}k = .000001 * (\frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n}){\log}.000001 * (\frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n})$ too small

Therefore, $k$ has to be somewhere in this vicinity, aka $k = \frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n}$. Note that $k = 1 * (\frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n})$, when c = 1

Pick $k = \frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n}$

$k*{\log}k = \frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n}{\log}\frac{{\log}n}{\log{\log}n}$ and somehow, this is supposed to equal $c{\log}n$? I'm unaware of a way to effectively simplify the expression. Tips and tricks or any help with the simplification would be appreciated

Comment: Suppose $n>2$ so $\log\log\log n$ exists. Then $c=(k\log k)/\log n=(\log\log n  -\log\log\log n)/\log n$.

Comment: why does n > 2 produce ${\log}{\log}{\log}n$ and why the choice of $c = k{\log}k/{\log}n$? It's unclear how this substitution into $k*{\log}k$ equals $c{\log}n$ as the question was for $k = \frac{{\log}n}{{\log}{\log}n}$ being substituted in $k*{\log}k$ is supposed to equal $c{\log}n$. Would you be able to expand and explain your reasoning more formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the question and log both sides just as you have done:

$$k \log{k} = c \log{n}$$

Using:

$$k = \frac{\log{n}}{\log{\log{n}}}$$

We get:

$$\frac{\log{n}}{\log{\log{n}}} \log{\frac{\log{n}}{\log{\log{n}}}} = c \log{n}$$

$$\frac{\log{n}}{\log{\log{n}}}\bigg(\log{\log{n}}-\log{\log{\log{n}}}\bigg) = c \log{n}$$

Simplifying:

$$1-\frac{\log{\log{\log{n}}}}{\log{\log{n}}}= c$$

Let's use the following equation to simplify that mess:

$$X = \log{\log{n}}$$

Yielding:

$$1 - \frac{\log{X}}{X} = c$$

$$X^{\frac{1}{X}} = 2^{1-c}$$

Consider $c = \frac{1}{2}$, this gives us:

$$X^{\frac{1}{X}} = 2^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Therefore, $X = 2$ and since $X = \log{\log{n}}$, $n = 16$

Let's check the equation with $c = \frac{1}{2}$ and $n = 16$

$$k ^ {k} = n^c$$

LHS = $k = \frac{\log{n}}{\log{\log{n}}}$ = 4, RHS = 4. I'm not sure if their intention is for us to derive that functional expression for $k$ but using the expression which they provided to us, the above illustrates how we can use it to determine a value for $n$ and $c$ in the form $n^c$ as the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Exact real solution of the equation
$$k^k = n^c$$
[can be expressed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5ELambertW%28c%20ln%20n%29) via Lambert W-function,
$$k=e^{W(c\ln n)}=\dfrac{c_1\log_2 n}{W(c_1\log_2 n)},$$
where $\;c_1=c\ln 2.\;$

If $\;x\in(0,1000),\;$ then
$$W(x)\approx 0.525\log_2(x).$$

[image: Lambert W vs log, n<1000]

However, for $\;x>>1000\;$ it does not work.

[image: Lambert W vs log, x>>1000]

Comment: Your expression after exp(W(c ln n)) should be base of base e instead of base 2

Comment: @JulieTaylor Thanks for the comment, detalized.